# How to 'stay up to date' in your field?

Tags: literature, literature-search, literature-review

In academia, it's important to stay up to date with the latest 'hot' hypotheses in the your field. By 'hot', I mean the hypothesis that are most important/topical/relevant/popular. Perhaps the best way of staying up to date in a given field is by reading the literature. But  I'm wondering if there are any shortcuts? Are there any websites or papers that list the current most 'hot' hypotheses in each field? Google Scholar lists the most cited papers but I'm wondering if any resource goes one step further by listing topics?

Comment: To my perception, there are so many implicit hypotheses in this question that it's hardly sensibly answerable. To begin, "hot hypotheses"? I don't object to the language, but... is this really the/a primary issue? And trusting Google Scholar's most-cited index as guide to reading? Surely the questioner is thinking of a far more specific field of inquiry... in which, conceivably, the premises make more sense?

Comment: @paulgarrett If we replace "hypotheses" with a near synonym like "conjectures" or "open problems," and also "hot" with "most important/topical/relevant/popular" (which OP says are his or her definition of "hot"), it may not be too absurd to find it important to stay up to date with the current statuses of "hot hypotheses" in mathematics. Maybe the problem is that mentioning most cited papers on Google Scholar suggests that by "hot," maybe OP  means "trendy," "fashionable," or something along those lines, which I think can contradict OP's claimed definition.

Comment: @YuichiroFujiwara, yes, tweaking the language can make the question semantically more sensible or definite, but/and then my reaction is something like "You don't want what you think you want..." :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Please have my upvote, sir.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest some ways of becoming up to date:

1. Following the related top scientists and authors on that field on Google Scholar
2. Following the related top researchers and professors web sites and their research lab and groups publications.
3. Ask to contribute to work for or work with them.
4. Check related Linked-In groups to know more about academia and industry.
5. Visit their labs and talk with them.
6. Take part in the related conferences.
7. Check the related conference proceedings. For example, the IEEE web site has lots options to help you.