# Is there an aggregated up to date list of published articles?

Tags: publications, online-publication

I'm thinking of an efficient way to stay up to date with recent news from given field (especially in mathematics and its subfields, but it perhaps does not matter for the question itself). Since there are hundreds or thousands of journals, then there are preprint archives such as arxiv.org, it seems quite inefficient to keep checking all of these separately.

So my question is, is there some aggregated service that would allow one to follow up new articels in given field(s)? This question [How to 'stay up to date' in your field?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36571/how-to-stay-up-to-date-in-your-field) seems to be related, and it mentions Google scholars. It just does not seem to allow much of a filtering, so I was interested in some alternatives. I was considering creating a service that would fetch data from different sites for such purpose, but I don't want to do anything that already exists...

Comment: Are you aware of zbMATH and MathSciNet?

Comment: @quid Not really, I think I have heard about MathSciNet, but not zbMATH. Going to check that out!

Comment: It looks good at least from what I am allowed, unfortunately for full access it requires institution subscription/affiliation, and I am not affiliated with university for quite a long time, do I need to get back to studies? :)

Comment: zbMATH provides limited access for free. It is the same model as MathSciNet; actually it's the 'original' in  away. There is/was also a Russian analogue. But I don't know much about that. // Besides the subscription issue, it should also be noted that  there is some delay incurred by the processing. .

Comment: This is really field-dependent.